# PostgreSQL exit status when running a file

Tags: postgresql

When running PostgreSQL with a single SQL command error codes are returned as expected:

```
% psql -c "SELECT * FROM AWDASDASDASDAS" my_db
ERROR:  relation "awdasdasdasdas" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM AWDASDASDASDAS
% echo $?
1
```

But when running a file, the error is suppressed:

```
% psql -f test.sql my_db
psql:test.sql:1: ERROR:  relation "awdasdasdasdas" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM AWDASDASDASDAS
% echo $?
0
```

Any idea how to get these errors back?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adding this to the first line of the SQL file does the trick:

```
\set ON_ERROR_STOP 1
```

New comments (Thanks!) suggest the following solutions:

```
-v ON_ERROR_STOP=1
-v ON_ERROR_STOP=on
```

Comment: @pt12lol That failed for me as well, this did work: `psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=on -f file_name.sql`